# Como exibir um modal(bootstrap) informando que o input type="file" não pode ser nulo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um input:

```
<input id="imagens" type="file" multiple name="file" accept="image/x-png, 
        image/gif, image/jpeg" required />
```

E o seguinte código javascript:

```
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("imagens");
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
enviar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (fileUpload.files.length == 0) {
        alert("Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado");
        return;
    }
})
```

Gostaria que, caso o usuário tentasse enviar o formulário sem imagens, fosse exibido um **modal do bootstrap** ao invés desse **alert**.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#modal-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi desta maneira:

HTML

```
 <input id="imagens" type="file" multiple name="file" accept="image/x-png, 
 image/gif, image/jpeg" required />
```

Jquery

```
  $("#target").submit(function (event) {
        var imgVal = $('#imagens').val();
        if (imgVal == '') {
            $('#myModal').modal('show')
        }
    });
```

Onde **target** é o id do meu formulário e **mymodal** é o id do meu modal.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez esse codigo com Jquery deve ajudar. Dentro desse IF(), não estou 100% certo disso mas creio que é nesse sentido

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

var $me = $(this);

$me.delay(3000).hide(0, function() {
    $me.modal('hide');
});
```

});

Exibe a modal por 3 segundos.